# Webpack cannot resolve custom module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, babeljs

I am using webpack and angular for one of my project. I have some custom angular modules (not es6) and without export statements. Every module is an individual folder and contains several files and I want to include them in my entry.js file to create bundle. But for some reason, my entry.js cannot resolve it. 
Project structure

Root

   modules

      moduleX

            moduleX.module.js

            moduleX.controller.js

            moduleX.core.js

      moduleY

            moduleY.module.js

            moduleY.controller.js

            moduleY.core.js

   entry.js

   webpack.config.js

I have webpack.config.js and vendors are loading properly with

```
module.exports = {
    debug: true,

    entry: {
        app: [
            './entry.js'
        ],....
```

and entry.js has

```
require.context(
  "./modules", 
  true, 
 /\.js$/
); 
angular
    .module('myapp', ['moduleX', 'moduleY']);
```

Webpack generates the app.bundle.js file with all the code inside custom modules files but still entry.js cannot resolve any module which i put as dependency. I am doing it wrong? Example code (See non es6 modules under src/modules/) https://github.com/PradipShrestha/webpack-demo

Comment: so this "module" what format does it follow ?? AMD?  you already said no export so that rules out commonjs and systemjs so what type of module is. if none why not?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon: Thank you Dayan. This is third party angular library which comes with template. It does not follow AMD or any other format it is just regular angular module. Is it not possible to work webpack with these modules?

Comment: i don't think. but you can include it in your index.html as a regular script tag and the angular code will pick it up